# jQuery not working for media uploader

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
jQuery.fn.upload_image = function( button ) {
    var button_id = button.attr('id');
    var field_id = button_id.replace( '_button', '' );

    // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
    if ( file_frame ) {
      file_frame.open();
      return;
    }

    // Create the media frame.
    file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_title' ),
      button: {
        text: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_button_text' ),
      },
      multiple: false
    });

    // When an image is selected, run a callback.
    file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
      var attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
      jQuery("#"+field_id).val(attachment.id);
      jQuery("#listingimage img").attr('src',attachment.url);
      jQuery( '#listingimage img' ).show();
      jQuery( '#' + button_id ).attr( 'id', 'remove_image_button' );
      jQuery( '#remove_image_button' ).text( 'Remove image' );
    });

    // Finally, open the modal
    file_frame.open();
};

jQuery('#listingimage').on( 'click', '#upload_image_button', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.fn.upload_listing_image( jQuery(this) );
});

jQuery('#listingimage').on( 'click', '#remove_image_button', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery( '#upload_image' ).val( '' );
    jQuery( '#listingimage img' ).attr( 'src', '' );
    jQuery( '#listingimage img' ).hide();
    jQuery( this ).attr( 'id', 'upload_image_button' );
    jQuery( '#upload_image_button' ).text( 'Set image' );
});
```

});

Comment: Can you please add some additional details showing how this code is enqueued and explain at what point you encounter the error?

Comment: This question is far to vague. Simply posting code and stating it is not working, will not get you a proper answer. Please provide additional details, as to what it is exactly you are trying to achieve, where you think it is failing, and also as @DaveRomsey pointed out, how it is being enqueued so we can try and figure out a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this "question" is horrible asked here,
i think his problem is that "file_frame.on( 'select'" seems not to work anymore, at least that's the issue I'm recently experiencing.

This seems to have something todo with an WordPress update, because this code worked in the past.